# LIKE pattern T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-like

I have wrote a phraser which is phrasing a quite long string into small pieces, after the phrasing of one item is completed, it removes him from @input and continue, until it wont be able to find any items to phrase.
I am selecting items based on LIKE pattern.

In some cases, there are however it is selecting some other parts of the message, and then it's end in infinitive loop.

The pattern I am looking for to be selected using LIKE clause is in format of :

> (Any number from 1 to 9) + (variable length A-Z only) + '/' +
>   (variable length A-Z only)+space of Cr or Lf or CrLf.

```
--This is what I do have: 
DECLARE @match NVarChar(100)
    SET @match  =  '%[1-9][a-z]%'

DECLARE @input1 varchar(max),@input2 varchar(max)  
    SET @input1 ='1ABCD/EFGH *W/17001588 *RHELLO SMVML1C'

DECLARE @position Int 
    SET @position = PATINDEX(@match, @input1);

SELECT @position;

--after the loop- it is also 'catching' the 1C at the end of the string: 

SET @input2     = '*W/17001588 *RHELLO SMVML1C'
SET @position   = PATINDEX(@match, @input2);

SELECT @position

---In order to eliminate this, I have tried to change @match:

SET @match  =  '%[1-9][a-z][/][a-z]%'

SET @position = PATINDEX(@match, @input1);
SELECT @position  --postion is  0, so the first item, that should have been selected, wasn't selected
SET @position   = PATINDEX(@match, @input2);
SELECT @position --postion is  0
```

Many thanks for help!

Comment: T-SQL doesn't have regular expressions or any other built-in pattern matcher that will do what you want. In particular the "any number of" and "variable length" parts are what is going to cause problems.

Comment: So on your new match, for `@input1`, `@position` should be 1 and for `@input2`,  `@position` should be 0? Correct?

Comment: You can't parse such input using the limited capabilities of PATINDEX. You should either use regular expressions in code or write an actual parser.

Comment: Have you considered using another tool?

Comment: With CLR and regex `[\d][A-Z]+/[A-Z]+[ \r\n]` this is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your match variable/criteria to this:

```
SET @match  =  '%[1-9][a-z]%[/][a-z]%'
```

This will get you the desired result.  Loosely translated it is saying "Get me the starting position of the first match where the pattern is [anything]-[number from 1-9]-[single letter from a-z]-[anything]-[slash]-[single letter from a-z]-[anything].
Hope this helps!

Comment: unfortunatly that won't match the variable length parts of his search, 1a/a matches 1abc/def doesn't. nore does it match the terminal character.

Comment: Actually it DOES match on 1abc/def....that's what the 2nd wildcard handles.  The question has also changed since I gave my answer (there was originally no terminal character, nor was the string immediately before the slash A-Z only)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments above; this is a regex problem that needs to be solved with regex tools. I would recommend the assembly created by SimpleTalk. [You can get their code and read their very thorough article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/).

Unfortunately this solution requires serious admin rights to the database and server, so it won't be portable as a script. But I think these functions are worth any effort it takes to get the installed if you develop on the same database on a regular basis.

Just be forwarned, regex is a real processing hog and undermines much of the indexing efficiency in SQL Server. Use it only when you can't use like.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solves your entire problem , but if you can prefix your input with a space, you can modify the pattern to avoid matching a number without a preceding space.

```
set @input = ' '+@input;
set @match = '% [1-9][a-z]%';
```

If you need your pattern to account for other whitespace like Cr and Lf, your pattern could look like this:

```
set @match = '%[ '+char(13)+char(10)+'][1-9][a-z]%';
```